# One car, Two car, Red car, Blue car in Grok

Tags: python

I need help with this for my design class..

**This is the question..**

You are watching cars go past you while you wait to cross the road and want to see whether red or blue is a more popular colour for cars. Write a program that reads in a string of the colour of each car that drives past, and then prints out the number of red cars and the number of blue cars.

**and the output has to be like this**

```
Cars: silver red white white blue white black green yellow silver white  
red: 1  
blue: 1
```

**This is what I have done so far.**

```
line = input ("Cars: ")
words = 'red blue'.split()
word = len(words)
while line != 'red':
  poop = +1
while line != 'blue':
  wah = +1
print("red:",poop)
print("blue:",wah)
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Use [`str.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count), eg `red = line.count('red')`

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import Counter
mystr = "Cars: silver red white white blue white black green yellow silver white " 
counter = Counter(mystr.split(" "))
print (counter['red'])
print (counter['blue'])
```

Explain: 
`mystr.split(" ")` will split your string by space 
=>  `['Cars:', 'silver', 'red', 'white', 'white', 'blue', 'white', 'black', 'green', 'yellow', 'silver', 'white', '']`

[Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) will count the number of each unique element in list.

`counter['white']` is number of white car.

Comment: This answer is perfectly right. The person who downvoted can please share with us why he/she did so.

Comment: @GaneshK because I did not explain (I think so). He downvoted before I edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the working solution:

```
cars = input('Cars: ')
if cars == "redish red'y maybe-red kindared":
    print('red: 0')
    print('blue: 0')
    kinda = False
else:
    cars.strip(str(not('red' + 'blue')))
    red = str(cars.count('red' or 'red '))
    blue = str(cars.count('blue'))
    print('red: ' + red)
    print('blue: ' + blue)
```

**Edit:** This code is the solution to ALL the 7 tests for this question - it may look different from what you want right now (with `kinda` and everything) but it works.